# how to change the supported file types in joomla file uploading

Tags: file-upload, joomla

I need to upload some files through my custom made component in back end. I did that and the file path is also inserted to the DB. I'm using `JFile` for uploading. I can upload all images and zip files but I cant upload PDF files.
The code I'm using to upload is:

```
JFile::upload( $file['tmp_name'], $filepath);
```

Where should I enter the supported file types in `JFile` Joomla class. Help me to upload PDF files.

My HTML code is:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <label for="uploaded"><?php echo JText::_( 'Upload file' ); ?>:</label>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="file" name="uploaded" value="" size="30" class="inputbox" /> 
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the Joomla docs with a few changes made:

```
$file = JFactory::getApplication()->input->files->get('uploaded');
$filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
$fileSize = $filename['size'];

$uploadedFileNameParts = explode('.',$filename);
$uploadedFileExtension = array_pop($uploadedFileNameParts);

$validFileExts = explode(',', 'zip,pdf,jpg');
$extOk = false;

foreach($validFileExts as $key => $value){
        if( preg_match("/$value/i", $uploadedFileExtension ) ){
                $extOk = true;
        }
}

if ($extOk == false || !$validFileExts) {
    // return an arror if the file type isn't allowed
    echo JText::_( 'INVALID EXTENSION' );
    return;
}
//check file size. If over 2MB, throw an error
else if ( $fileSize > 2000000 ){
    echo JText::_( 'FILE BIGGER THAN 2MB' );
    return;
}
else {
    // your upload script
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah..thats solved my pblm..thank u Lodder... i think the if condition u accidently use the name $validFileTypes instead of $validFileExt..??

Comment: how can i specify the file size limit also in the above code??

Comment: @user007 - I've updated my answer. The code for it is in the `else if ()` statement and the definition is `$fileSize = $filename['size'];` which I added towards the top of the script

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Joomla model form to create a upload field?
If yes - try to define "accept" parameter in field attributes.
More info here: http://docs.joomla.org/File_form_field_type

Updated answer:
Try to use this code instead

```
$file = JFactory::getApplication()->input->files->get('uploaded');
$filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
$fileSize = $filename['size'];

$uploadedFileNameParts = explode('.',$filename);
$uploadedFileExtension = array_pop($uploadedFileNameParts);

$validFileExts = array('zip', 'pdf', 'jpg');
$extension = JFile::getExt($file['name']);

if (!in_array($extension, $validFileExts)) {
    // return an arror if the file type isn't allowed
    echo JText::_( 'INVALID EXTENSION' );
    return;
}
//check file size. If over 2MB, throw an error
else if ( $fileSize > 2000000 ){
    echo JText::_( 'FILE BIGGER THAN 2MB' );
    return;
}
else {
    // your upload script
}
```

Comment: i use input field inside table

Comment: JFile::upload(); method itself doesn't validate allowed file types.
Can you also add your Model's code?

Comment: i updated the ques with the uploading code and db saving code